# How to specify cacheDirectory option when using babel-loader with webpack?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

There is a [cacheDirectory](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#options) option in babel-loader. I can't figure out how to use it with the following webpack setup:

```
var compiler = webpack( {
    context: path.resolve( __dirname + "/../../" + rootModuleDir + "/" + modules[ module ] ),
    entry: "./index.jsx",
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve( __dirname + "/../../assets/js/lib/react" ),
        extensions: [ "", ".js", ".jsx" ]
    },
    output: {
        path: targetDir,
        filename: modules[ module ] + ".js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader?optional=runtime" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        //new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin( {
            filename: "[file].map"
        } )
    ]
} );
```

Where should it go?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add it to the babel-loader configuration like this:

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader?optional=runtime&cacheDirectory"
    }
]
```

Note, you should not add `=true`, that's unnecessary and will set the `cacheDirectory` to be use a directory named `true`. Reference: [using cacheDirectory fails with Error](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#using-cachedirectory-fails-with-enoent-error)

You can also use the `query` property:

```
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
            optional: "runtime",
            cacheDirectory: true
        }
    }
]
```

When using the `query` property, specifying `true` will enable the option, and specifying a string value will enable the option and configure it to use that directory name. Reference: [query parameters](https://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html#query-parameters)

Comment: According to the babel docs, `=true` will cause the loader to use the default cache directory. See https://github.com/babel/babel-loader

Comment: I fix `syntax` error for missing `,` and `rules` instead of `loaders`

Answer (score 3):

With `babel-loader` v8/9+ you specify `options` like this:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: [/node_modules/],
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        cacheDirectory: true,
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this -

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader?+cacheDirectory'
      }
    ]
  } 
};
```

It will cache in `node_modules/.cache/babel-loader` folder.

Files would be stored something like this -

`0065e42bfc1ab4c292dfa71c6a0e924b59ed6a37.json.gz`  `538205e2b3bffa535d934c3d8f2feee4566bfc00.json.gz`
`b17d9d4b73726f4ba7c5797a9959546fb3d72d69.json.gz`

Different cache file for each JS file.

Refer documentation here - https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#options

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the loader string like so:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader?optional=runtime&cacheDirectory=true" }
    ]
},
```

Comment: I already tried to. But it doesn't seem to cache anything since the time needed to `webpack` bundles remains the same.

Comment: Note that you can try to pass some path to it besides a boolean. When set true, it should use OS default directory. Maybe this helps in debugging.

Comment: babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true
worked for me.  Cut my times from ~6s to ~1s.

Comment: @iambrandonn I use it too. But it seems not to boost first build speed. Does it work?

Comment: It's a cache, so it shouldn't make any difference on the "first build speed". But when working, it should reduce the time on subsequent builds.